# Slide multi Level Menu

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to make multi level menu as mmenu.jquery. Why the event is not processed by the link and why the menu does not go to the next level? What's my mistake? What am I doing wrong?.................................................................................................................................

```js
var menuWrap = $('nav');
var rootMenu = $('.menu ul');
var currentMenu;

function setMenu(menu)
{
    var level = menu.parents('ul').length;

    menu.show();
    menuWrap.css('height', menu.height());
    rootMenu.css('left', -100 * level + '%');
    currentMenu = menu;

    rootMenu.one('transitionend', function(){
        menu.find('ul').hide();
    });
}

$('.menu a').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $(this).siblings('ul');
});
```

```css
html, body {
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
  }
  ul {
   padding: 0;
   margin: 0;
  }
  li {
   list-style-type: none;
  }
  a {
   display: inline-block;
   vertical-align: top;
   text-decoration: none;
   font-size: 20px;
   color: #fff;
   background-color: #4588ca;
      width: 100%;
      padding: 0 20px;
  }
  nav {
   width: 500px;
   position: relative;
   margin: 10px;
   background-color: #324b5c;
  }
  nav ul {
      list-style: none;
      transition: -webkit-transform 0.3s;
      transition: transform 0.3s;
      transition: transform 0.3s, -webkit-transform 0.3s;
      position: relative;
      left: 0;
      top: 0;
      width: 100%;
  }
  nav ul ul {
      display: none;
      position: absolute;
      left: 100%;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav role="navigation">
  <ul class="menu">
    <li> 
      <a href="">Cataloge</a>
      <ul class="menu">
        <li>
          <a href="#">Electrical goods</a>
          <ul class="menu">
            <li>
              <a href="#">Drill</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#">Screwdriver</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#">Hammer</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Mixer</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Bathrooms</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Anonses</a> 
      <ul class="menu i-dropdown-content">
        <li>
          <a href="#">Anons 1</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Anons 2</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Anons 3</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">More</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Contacts</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: `$('.menu a').click(setMenu(rootMenu));`  `setMenu()` does not return a function which is expected as a callback for the click event.

Comment: @Taplar, I rewrite code.